# Define task order without dependency in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

#### Question

Can I somehow make sure that a task will be executed before/after another task, when both of them are to be executed? I *don't* want to add a dependency between them that's always there.

#### Background

I have two tasks, one that starts a server and one that runs tests against it. The task that starts that server runs it in a new process, so I can run `gradle startServer runServerTests`. Since it takes some time to start the server, it must be possible to start a server with one gradle process and then run the tests several times with another gradle process.

Now I'm trying to create a single task that does all that our CI environment does, which includes starting a server and running the server tests. I obviously want to make sure that the server is started before running the tests, but so far I'm out of luck.

#### Attempts

My first attempt is below, but that does not work since the order of the defined dependencies [is not guaranteed](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-427):

```
task doItAll(dependsOn: [startServer, runServerTests]) { ... }
```

My second attempt, calling the tasks [in actions](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Running-a-task-after-execution-of-another-task-td4405504.html) does not work and [is not supported](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/1-0-m-7-Gradle-idea-task-fails-with-lock-exception-td5123405.html):

```
task doItAll() << {
  tasks.startServer.execute()
  tasks.runServerTests.execute()
}
```

Solutions are on the roadmap ([GRADLE-294](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-294), [Initializer/Finalizer](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/improving_tasks-19op1r)), but that doesn't help me now.

Comment: I've read the Gradle dev mailing lists off and on over the past couple years and imo Gradle suffers from overengineering. Some of your links are evidence of this -- you see relatively basic/fundamental bugs and feature requests languish in Jira for over four years with no activity because "they'll all be taken care of after the next big refactor/rearchitecture [not an actual quote but a mindset]". Of course they can't be fixed ahead of that refactor because that would be a "hack". Classic overengineering.

Comment: I would add though that I think it is a great tool in its current form  -- despite some of its issues and the process issues which I mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It probably won't help you much at the moment, but but I have submitted a pull request in this area recently and it was hinted that it should make it into 1.6 (they are currently releasing 1.5 and the PR didn't make it into that release) - see the discussion [here](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Must-run-after-ordering-td5710924.html) . Your best bet is to wait for the [pull request](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/134) to be merged into master after 1.5 release and then grab the first available nightly build from [here](http://www.gradle.org/nightly).

**EDIT**

Gradle 1.6 has been released some time ago and now you can simply use `mustRunAfter` to achieve that. See [the section on task ordering in Gradle manual](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec%3aordering_tasks) for details.

Comment: Good job, that looks awesome!

Comment: Since this is in the [nightly docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/nightly/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks) by now, I'm assuming it'll make it to the next release.

Comment: yep, it looks like it will be in 1.6

Comment: Since the feature is now a part of the public Gradle API, could you please update your answer with a feature description on how to use it?

Comment: Hope that this should be enough

Answer (score 2):

The gradle Task enhancements [finalizedBy](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#setFinalizedBy%28java.lang.Iterable%29) and [mustRunAfter](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#setMustRunAfter%28java.lang.Iterable%29) go some way to solving these issues. However, like the OP I had a need to change the dependencies and finalization based on *the tasks requested*, not statically defined.

I wanted **gradle integrationTest** to execute **startup**, **runTests** and finalized by **shutdown**. 
I also wanted **startup**, **runTests** and **shutdown** to be able to be run independently - without any dependencies or finalization.

You could statically create wrapper tasks that could express this, however it didn't scale well as the number and complexity of startup and shutdown tasks increased - and relied on anyone adding more tasks to add and maintain the required wrappers.

More elegant I found was to implement **integrationTests** as a task rule.

```java
tasks.addRule('integrationTest: Full execution of integration tests with setup, startup,  shutdown and clean up') { String taskName ->
    if (taskName.equals('integrationTest')) {
        task(dependsOn: [runTests], taskName)

        // Add ordering and finalization for integration test runs        
        runTests.dependsOn startup
        startup.finalizedBy shutdown

        ... // and many other setup and shutdown tasks you want in the task DAG when running an integration test
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-294 was resolved 1st May (Gradle 1.6) and now gives you a way to describe that task B should run before A, if both are present when using a mustRunAfter() relationship between tasks.

I therefore think your question is fully answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your ordering problem by explicitly declaring a single task dependency:

```
runServerTests.dependsOn startServer

task doItAll(dependsOn: runServerTests) << {
   // do something
}
```

There's [work in the pipeline](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/design-docs/deploying-applications-for-testing.md) that addresses your specific use case for bringing up another component e.g. a Servlet container for testing purposes.

Comment: Specifying `runServerTests.dependsOn startServer` like this will _always_ make `startServer` run before the task `runServerTests` is executed. I tried to be clear that this is _not_ what I wanted, but maybe I wasn't clear enough?

Comment: Then I must have misunderstood your requirements. I thought that's what you needed. What's the condition under which you want the server to be started?

Comment: I want the server to be started before `runServetTests`, but only when a user executes `doItAll`. I want to keep the ability I have today to execute `runServerTests` on an already running server. The server may be started by executing `startServer` manually earlier, which leaves the server running in a background process.

Comment: Ah, OK. When you say `startServer` can be started manually, does that mean that it can also happen in a different Gradle process or is always part of the same process?

Comment: Yes, it can happen in a different Gradle process.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge a while back - here's what I did to address it (full story):

https://caffeineinduced.wordpress.com/2015/01/25/run-a-list-of-gradle-tasks-in-specific-order/

*TLDR; version:*

```
//--- build aliases : define a synonym here if you want a shortcut to run multiple targets

def buildAliases = [
   'all' : ['clean', 'assemble', 'runProvisioner', 'stopTomcat', 'installTomcat', 'deployToTomcat', 'startTomcat'],
   'rebuild' : ['clean', 'assemble']
]
def expandedTaskList = []

gradle.startParameter.taskNames.each {
    expandedTaskList << (buildAliases[it] ? buildAliases[it] : it)
}

gradle.startParameter.taskNames = expandedTaskList.flatten()

println "\n\n\texpanded task list: ${gradle.startParameter.taskNames }\n\n"
```

Comment: Please try to post the solution, or at least a minimal part of it in your answer. If not, the link may die long before the question/answer is removed from OS.