# Is there an appropriate way to model "execute after" but not "depends on" for a Gradle task?

Tags: gradle

I'm not sure if it's possible, but I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
task myTask(executeAfter: myOtherTask) << {
     //do something
}
```

where myTask will wait for myOtherTask to complete before executing, but if myOtherTask wasn't explicitly named during the build script invocation, it will not be executed as a dependency of myTask (like dependsOn would cause to happen).

I had the idea to use [ExpandoMetaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ExpandoMetaClass) to add this, though I'm not sure if it can really be implemented this way in Gradle's lifecycle.

```
Task.metaClass.executeAfter = { dependencyTask ->
     if(<some condition>) {
         this.dependsOn(dependencyTask)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is [in the works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15283605/555642) but not available yet. Pull request is [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/134).

Comment: That pull request has already been merged. It will be part of Gradle 1.6.

Comment: And if really need it now and you don't mind being on the bleeding edge it should also be available in the latest [nightly build](http://www.gradle.org/nightly)